# how to introduce an empty line to stop a for/while loop from receiving user input

Tags: java

My assignment:

> Write a program that reads user input **until an empty line**. For
> each non-empty string, the program splits the string by spaces and
> then prints the pieces that contain the letter g, each on a new line.
>
> Expected output:
>
> ```
> java programming language
> programming 
> language
>
> programming courses
> programming
>
> other courses
> ```
>
> (loop must stop from receiving user input, because the last string does not contain letter g)

Here is my attempt and code:

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (true) {
    String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] splitArray = userInput.split(" ");

    for (int loopString = 0; loopString < splitArray.length; loopString++) {
        if (splitArray[loopString].contains("g")) {
            System.out.println(splitArray[loopString]);
        } else if (userInput.equals("")) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

1. I have tried to introduce an empty line within `(userInput.equals(""))`, but loop continues infinitely without breaking.
2. I have also tried to add `else if(!splitArray[loopString].contains("g")) {break;}`, but I couldn't find the result I am looking for.

**Goal**: I want to keep writing sentences that contain the letter G and eventually want to write a sentence that hasn't got the letter G to stop the loop at that point.

How can I approach such a problem and how to solve it in a linear way?

Answer (score 0):

You `break` is not in the right place. But in any case, you should keep a "containsG" flag and exit if the last line did not have a g

```
boolean containsG;
do {
    containsG = false;
    String userInput = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] splitArray = userInput.split(" ");

    for (int loopString = 0; loopString < splitArray.length; loopString++) {
        if (splitArray[loopString].contains("g")) {
            System.out.println(splitArray[loopString]);
            containsG = true;
        }
    }
    
} while (containsG);
```

Comment: I have changed the letter G to AV and the code runs perfectly, but when I input the following string it stops the loop after inputting it: mediocre average avenged aviary, is there an explanation behind that or am I missing something?